# Issues with background when transform: rotateY(), problem seems to only occur in codepen(?)

Tags: html, css, codepen

I am trying to create a 3D Flip Card in codepen, and whenever I hover the card its content is supposed to rotate along the Y axis.
If I try to do that in codepen, the background of the card front basically becomes transparent, so that the background of the card back appears and vice versa.

I have tried out the same code, running it in my browser (Chrome and Firefox) and works just fine.

I have also already tried to play around with transform-style: preserve-3d; as well as backface-visibility: hidden; .
Still it doesn't seem to work.

Is this just a bug in CodePen since it works in my normal browsers or what is the reason for that.

Here is my code:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card {
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card__content {
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
  position: relative;
 }

.card:hover .card__content {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__front, .card__back {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

.card__front {
 background: red;
}

 .card__heading {
 transform: translateZ(2rem);
}
.card__desc {
 transform: translateZ(3rem);
}

.card__back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 background: blue;
}
.card__body {
 max-width: 60%;
 transform: translateZ(4rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <div class="card__content">
   <div class="card__front">
     <p class="card__desc">
       This would be some text
     </p>
     <h1 class="card__heading">
       Your Heading
     </h1>
   </div>
   <div class="card__back">
     <p class="card__body">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/xutocode/pen/KKaNQqY?editors=1100
There you can see, how the red background of the card's front changes to blue when hovering, before even rotating.
So again: is this a common bug in CodePen?

Comment: Codepen seems to be working fine for me on Chrome 89.0.4389.90 MacOS. Maybe you are checking codepen and written code in different browsers? This might be a browser support issue.

Comment: Ah yes. That's true. For checking I used Chrome and Firefox MacOs, but I wrote the codepen using the latest Safari version, and now I double checked and you were right. With Safari it also didn't work. Do you have any idea how that could be, since Safari browser should actually work for those transforms? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Safari often causes support issues with some modern CSS concepts like flexbox grid etc. My guess is it could have something to do with transform or transform-style. Moreover you did not use css prefixes for these properties so that could also be the issue. Will need to check in detail to be sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems safari is causing problems with `backface-visibility`. It doesn't seem to be supported without the `webkit` prefix. Try the following it seems to work on safari for me.

```css
.card__front, .card__back {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```